# Does Arma 2 Free have a sandbox mode?

Tags: arma-2

I often play Arma 2 Free with friends, but I would like to know if there is a way we can play in a "sandbox". By "sandbox" I mean a map full of different vehicles, so we can test them out and have fun without enemies.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

There doesnt seem to be a "sandbox mode" per say, but it would appear you can get/make a sandbox map that meets your criteria quite easily.

I'd look around http://arma2.filefront.com/ for what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

Create a mission yourself.

Its simple enough to add vehicles